Visualizing multiple graphs in a single figure while conserving space and maintaining clarity
I'm visualizing a graph using the given code, where each pair of nodes connected by a comma represents an edge, and the numeric value represents the intensity of that edge. Here is the code for a graph:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import os
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
data = {
    ('A', 'B'): 0.71,
    ('M', 'B'): 0.67,
    ('N', 'B'): 0.64,
    ('A', 'O'): 0.62,
    ('O', 'B'): 0.60,
    ('N', 'O'): 0.53,
    ('M', 'O'): 0.46,
    ('A', 'N'): 0.18,
    ('M', 'N'): 0.11
}


G = nx.Graph()
for key, value in data.items():
    G.add_edge(*key, weight=value)


fig, axe = plt.subplots()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=123456)
# Define the base color
base_color = (0, 0, 1)  # Blue color
base_color = mcolors.to_rgb('tab:red')# Blue color


# Get the edge weights
weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')

# Create a function to adjust the color intensity
def adjust_color_intensity(base_color, weight):
    """ Adjust color intensity based on weight. """
    return tuple(weight * x + (1 - weight) * 1 for x in base_color)


# Generate the edge colors based on weights
edge_colors = [adjust_color_intensity(base_color, weight) for weight in weights.values()]
rgb_color = (1,0,0)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=axe, node_color='tab:blue')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=axe, edge_color=edge_colors)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=12, ax=axe)
plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close(fig)

Now, I'd like to add more graphs to the image while ensuring that it doesn't take up too much space and that the edges, visualization, and node fonts remain clear. The graphs I want to add are:
Graph2: ('ABC', 'ADC'): 0.53
Graph3: ('CDE', 'CFH'): 0.28
Graph4: ('GHI', 'GMI'): 0.20
Graph5: ('XYZ', 'XWZ'): 0.17

Can anyone help me with visualizing multiple graphs in a single figure?

you may want to use subplots

I'm not sure I totally follow your requirements, but here I've taken your code, put it inside some functions and plotted each graph inside a separate Axes object within a single figure.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import os
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors


def adjust_color_intensity(base_color, weight):
    """ Adjust color intensity based on weight. """
    return tuple(weight * x + (1 - weight) * 1 for x in base_color)


def draw(data,axe,node_size=100,font_size=12):
    """Draw a graph of `data` on the Axes object `axe`"""
    G = nx.Graph()
    for key, value in data.items():
        G.add_edge(*key, weight=value)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=123456)

    # Define the base color
    base_color = (0, 0, 1)  # Blue color
    base_color = mcolors.to_rgb('tab:red')# Blue color

    # Get the edge weights
    weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')

    # Generate the edge colors based on weights
    edge_colors = [adjust_color_intensity(base_color, weight) for weight in weights.values()]
    rgb_color = (1,0,0)
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=axe, node_color='tab:blue', node_size=node_size)
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=axe, edge_color=edge_colors)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=font_size, ax=axe)

the_data = [
('Graph1', {
    ('A', 'B'): 0.71,
    ('M', 'B'): 0.67,
    ('N', 'B'): 0.64,
    ('A', 'O'): 0.62,
    ('O', 'B'): 0.60,
    ('N', 'O'): 0.53,
    ('M', 'O'): 0.46,
    ('A', 'N'): 0.18,
    ('M', 'N'): 0.11}),
('Graph2', {('ABC', 'ADC'): 0.53}),
('Graph3', {('CDE', 'CFH'): 0.28}),
('Graph4', {('GHI', 'GMI'): 0.20}),
('Graph5', {('XYZ', 'XWZ'): 0.17}),
]
# how wide (inches) should each panel in the plot be?
pan_wid = 2

n = len(the_data)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, n, figsize=(pan_wid*n,pan_wid))
for i, (title, data) in enumerate(the_data):
    ax = axs[i]
    draw(data,ax,node_size=500,font_size=9)
    ax.set_title(title)
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()

The result looks like this:


Thank you for the response, @Mr Felix U I appreciate the provided solution. However, I would like to position Graph 2 to Graph 5 to the right of Graph 1, arranged from top to bottom, in order to save space.

Felix Additionally, is it possible to reduce the length of the edges in Graph 2 to Graph 5 in order to bring the nodes closer together?

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/index.html has examples of how to lay out the subplots, the one that looks very similar to what you want is https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/gridspec_and_subplots.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-gridspec-and-subplots-py.  Regarding the actual graphs inside each axis, you could look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axes_margins.html

Use this function to create each graph:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

def create_graph(data, ax, title):
    G = nx.Graph()
    for key, value in data.items():
        G.add_edge(*key, weight=value)
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G, seed=123456)
    base_color = mcolors.to_rgb('tab:red')
    weights = nx.get_edge_attributes(G, 'weight')
    def adjust_color_intensity(base_color, weight):
        return tuple(weight * x + (1 - weight) * 1 for x in base_color)

    edge_colors = [adjust_color_intensity(base_color, weight) for weight in weights.values()]
    nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, ax=ax, node_color='tab:blue')
    nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, ax=ax, edge_color=edge_colors)
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos, font_size=10, ax=ax)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.axis('off')

When calling plt.subplots, adjust the first two numbers to specify how many rows and columns your visualization should have.
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(18, 10))  # rows - 2, columns - 3

